# Seeing my past "not well-received" questions

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

It seems that I'm close to being banned from asking, I see the following message when trying to make a question:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I made a some research on Meta and found other users with the same issue. I would to make a question and a suggestion.

The question is: **How can I know which question(s) triggered the alert?**

I can't find my banned/deleted/flagged questions anywhere and clicking "deleted recent questions" on my profile shows no questions.

I think that **if someone gets this message he/she should be able to know exactly what question triggered the ban mechanism**... That's the suggestion, as a *feature-request*. There are several reasons why a question may trigger the mechanism.

From the article (https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe I'm *off-topic* often? Or maybe my *formatting/grammar/spelling* is poor? How can someone answer themselves these questions know without seeing the "offending" question?

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that the unfortunate outcome of informing a user exactly what question(s) triggered the ban will be that they may be tempted to perform minimalist edits on just that or those question(s) instead of participating in a broader learning experience.

Question bans can be imposed quite quickly, but are not imposed lightly, and indicate that there have been multiple questions which have not been well received.

I suspect that there will have been such an issue in most, if not all questions asked by a user thus banned, so I think it better to have the person with an asking ban review all, or at least many, of their closed and downvoted questions after (re-)familiarizing themselves with the site's [help/how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page to see what they can do to improve their asking style.

Comment: Or, in other words, something like this: "Which post triggered the ban?" "All of them!"

Comment: @PolyGeo Nailed it. It's hard to be motivating _and_ not be a carrot on a stick at the same time. _Go fix this and this and this_ is not nearly as powerful as _Here's how to do it so you never have to go fix stuff._. This  is hard, actually.

Comment: I agree that seeing some sort of less vague criteria, or an outline of the thresholds would be useful.